# Any examples of Bitcoins being used to buy bonds to build a Digital Community

Tags: ripple, qrcode

Does anyone have examples of bitcoins being used to buy bonds to build a digital community?

Comment: where bond = In finance, a bond is an instrument of indebtedness of the bond issuer to the holders. It is a debt security, under which the issuer owes the holders a debt and, depending on the terms of the bond, is obliged to pay them interest (the coupon) and/or to repay the principal at a later date, termed the maturity.

Comment: and security = QR code linked to domain sub-url or equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many examples of this. This is where you'd read about them: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=78.0. The US Government doing what they can to deny access to US citizens. The government of this free country doesn't like it when people have money outside of their control. You'll read that both BTC-TC and bitfunder were recently threatened out of business even though they were based in Belize. Of course, the US Government won't allow something so unregulated within the borders either.

Comment: thanks for your reply ... i've joined bitcointalk, and agree, there are active discussions around the pro's and con's with creating a bitcoin futures market ...